# SingnalR IIS AngularJS Performance Issue

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, signalr

I have an application running on IIS 7.5. It uses angularJS, HTML5, MVC4.

I'm using SignalR for managing some push events from the IIS.

When I start the application, signalR takes a lot of time to get going. Has any one faced such an issue before? Please help.

Attaching the calls which takes all the time. They are the next calls just after negotiation is complete.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the capabilities of your browser, SignalR wants to open up a web socket to keep a connection with your Hub on the server side.  Does the application hang? can you check the IIS logs to see if there was an authentication issue?  Depending on how you deployed this, you make not have the same auth setup in IIS that you have in your IDE using IIS Express.